# Redirecting .bat file to Java textarea

Tags: java, batch-file, jtextarea

Is it possible to redirect a batch file being executed onclick with JButton and output the contents inside of a JTextArea and keep the cmd prompt window from appearing? So basically the JTextArea would serve as the console.

Answer (score 1):

Yes possible, you need to read the output+error streams from `ProcessBuilder/Runtime` and push the read contents to JTextArea.